# java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value MySQL with JDBC

Tags: mysql, jdbc, utf-8

I use MySQL db for my project.I want to save data with jdbc.But there is a problem with some characters.For example ğ,ş.My connection url is below.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kutuphane useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

But I am getting java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x9F\xC4\x9F\xC4\x9F' error.I have tried all of the methods in this site but it is not solving the problem.Even though it saves , at this time record's character is failing.Not display ğ,ş etc.Is it a mysql bug or not?

Comment: The issue is most likely in the character set of the table. Try to execute your insert in MySQL CLI and see what error you get there.

Comment: I have tried and get no error.It is saving.

Comment: Is the SQLException coming from an INSERT?  (In utf8 encoding, hex C49F is ğ  "latin small letter g with breve" - a Turkish character)

Comment: Yes it comes from insert

Comment: You have `SET NAMES utf8` (or equivalent)?  The column receiving that text is declared to be `CHARACTER SET utf8`?  (Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

Comment: *"Is it a mysql bug or not?"* - No, it is not a bug. You are simply trying to insert UTF-8 characters into a column that cannot accept them. As @RickJames suggested, please [edit] your question to show us the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE.

Comment: Ok.I solved the problem.I change the characterSet of  DB to UTF-8.Now it is working well

Answer (score 3):

> Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x9F\xC4\x9F\xC4\x9F'

You are trying to insert UTF-8 characters into a column that cannot accept them. You must ensure that the COLLATION (character set) of the *column* is compatible with UTF-8.

That column setting may have been explicitly set, or it may have just used the default setting for the table (which may or may not have used the default value for the database, which in turn may or may not have used the default value for the server).

`SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` will tell you what the current settings are. If you see something like

```sql
CREATE TABLE `utf8test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `textcol` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_cs
```

then you will not be able to insert arbitrary UTF-8 characters into `textcol` until you do something like

```sql
ALTER TABLE utf8test 
    CHANGE COLUMN textcol textcol VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: My table is UTF-8 anyway.Although it is UTF-8 I can not insert to it

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports by default utf8 where characters are represented by 3 characters. For 4-byte characters you need to use utf8mb4 instead.